# Building aggregate tables IN SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am very new to SQL Server and SSIS.I am looking for a solution to build aggregate tables in SQL server. Currently we have all the fact tables by Day. I would like to buld Aggregate tables by Week,Month and Quarter.

Since I am new to SSIS. it would be of great help if you can guide me how to get started in SSIS to build the aggregates for reporting

```
ActivityDate    Product ID  Sales   Unit cost
-----------------------------------------------
6/20/2015       23456    $75.00      $35.17 
6/20/2015       23457    $83.00      $45.00 
6/20/2015       23458    $91.00      $31.33 
6/20/2015       23459    $99.00      $12.67 
6/20/2015       23460    $107.00     $5.00
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add to your question what you have tried so far.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clearly state what you have tried so far and what is the desired output that you require. For example you could do the following:

SELECT ActivityDate, [Product Id], Sales, Unit_Cost, Month(ActivityDate), Day(AcitivtyDate), Year(AcitivtyDate) 
From Table A

You can then create a Table and group by the following if required.